# MongoDB: If MapReduce is set to non atomic, what happens to newly written data?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, schema, atomic

I'm planning on building an application as follows:

- Node server receives logs from mobile devices and is inserted into Mongo as they come.
- An incremental MapReduce job is ran to calculate new fields from the data.
- The data is then pre-aggregated by minutes, hours, days, etc.
- All the while, the data in mongo is queried by a front-end visualization app.

I have a couple concerns:

- If I set the nonAtomic flag to true, what happens if new data is being written to the db as the MapReduce job runs?

  - Is it written to the db? If so, I'm assuming this data wouldn't be included in the current         incremental MapReduce job.
  - Or, is the database locked and the write is lost?
- As the MapReduce job and then the time aggregations run, can existing data already in the database be served to my front-end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following describes MongoDB 2.6. `nonAtomic` is an option for the `out` portion of map/reduce. It's not related to how map/reduce is ingesting documents from the source collection, only how it is outputting documents to the target collection.

Map/reduce uses a cursor over the input documents (created from `query`, `sort`, `limit`), so the rules for cursors apply to input documents to map/reduce.

When `nonAtomic` is `false`, during the `out` stage of the map/reduce, the output database is locked, so writes to that database will have to wait, and will possibly time out as failures on the client.

If `nonAtomic` is `true`, while the `out` stage of a map/reduce is running, data can be read from the database and served to the front end, but since the reads can interleave with the output from the map/reduce, the data served may be in an intermediate state.

Comment: What do you mean by "the data served may be in an intermediate state"?

Comment: Not yet fully reduced